# Querying a tinymce editor and entering text in Cypress

Tags: angular, cypress, tinymce

I am trying to query a text editor that was built using tinymce, so that I can enter text. However, when I run the test, it passes, but I do not see the text inside the text editor. The test I have written below tries to query the editor by using **formcontrolname**. This text editor also exists inside an iFrame. I have attached an image of where the element is inside the DOM. The front end is using Angular 16.2.12. Any ideas or suggestions as to what I can do to solve this?

```
describe("Setting Up Template", () => {
  TestRunner.addTestCase(
    "Can create an Email Template",
    [Users.User1],
    () => {
      cy.get(`[formcontrolname="body"]`, { timeout: 900 }).type("HELLO");
      });
    }
  );
});
```

[image]